# How to use Crypto++ to create a license key manager (generator and checker)?

Tags: c++, crypto++, license-key

I would like to know how most of the software developers create their own licensing key system.

I would like to create my own one for my software application.

I believe it is something related to cryptography.

As I am already using **Crypto++** library in my application for **MD5** and **SHA1** hashing, I would be happy and thankful if someone with expertise explain to me how to do it.

**NB:** I mainly use **C++** in my coding.

Also, I need it to be related to a hardware number obtained from a USB connected SIM card in the format of **123456789**, so the end-user will only send me that number and I will send him back the license key.

TIA.

Comment: one simple way is to sign your licence with a private key which your application can verify using a public key

Comment: *"I believe it [licensing scheme] is something related to cryptography..."* - You should probably purchase an off-the-shelf solution. It will save you a lot of time and effort. Otherwise, you need to learn a fair amount of crypto, an fair amount of info on ELF and PE formats, and figure out how to integrate your protection scheme into your executable so it detects tampering and is hard to remove. The actual key part and generating signatures is relatively easy.

Comment: @jww I don't care about software crackers, Because I am gonna need to pack my software with some strong packer, even though they can crack it, at least it will make it harder a bit. The part I am looking for is "Keygening process - developer part."